# Iterating through a Wordpress Object REACT js

Tags: reactjs

i am new to REACT.js and your advise would be much appreciated

- i have a list of categories i have placed a post under
- how do i display these list of categories in react js?

[image]

**i tried the below:**

```
<ul>
  {post.categories.map((category) => {
    return(
      <li>{category.name}</li>
    );
  })};
</ul>
```

**but i get the error:
TypeError: post.categories.map is not a function**
[image]

**BELOW ARE MY FILES**

app/scr/components/Blog/Index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout/Layout';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


class Index extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Layout>
        <ul>
          {this.props.posts.map((post) => {
            if (post) {
              return(
                <li key={post.ID} className="card">
                  <div>{post.title}</div>
                  <div>{post.date}</div>
                  <ul>
                    {post.categories.map((category) => {
                      return(
                        <li>{category.name}</li>
                      );
                    })};
                  </ul>
                </li>
              );
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          })}
        </ul>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

app/scr/containers/BlogBuilder/BlogIndexBuilder.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BlogIndex from '../../components/Blog/Index';
import axios from 'axios';

class BlogIndexBuilder extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/emma.wordpress.com/posts"
      )
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ posts: res.data.posts });
        console.log(this.state.posts);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  parseOutScripts(content) {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <BlogIndex 
        posts={this.state.posts}
       />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BlogIndexBuilder;
```

app/scr/components/Layout/Layout.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';

const layout = (props) => {
  return(
    <Aux>
      <main>{props.children}</main>
    </Aux>
  )
};

export default layout;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `map` over an object.  It needs to be an array.  You can transform it to an array if you want by using `Object.values(post.categories)`:

```js
<ul>
  {Object.values(post.categories).map((category) => {
    return(
      <li>{category.name}</li>
    );
  })};
</ul>
```